# TeXlipse build project problem in Windows 7

Tags: eclipse

After I installed Windows 7 (and reinstalled MikTeX, eclipse and TeXlipse) I couldn't build my LaTeX projects. I'm trying to compile TeXlipse project however following error message appears in the console

```
pdflatex.exe> pdflatex.exe: A required file system path could not be retrieved.
pdflatex.exe> pdflatex.exe: Data: 28
```

All tex paths are set properly, I'm still able to launch `pdflatex` in windows command line utility, but Eclipse's magic `ctrl+B` is broken. Did anybody face such problem?

Comment: Are you able to preview documents with ctrl+4? I'm working on Windows 7 + texlipse as well, and I can't build neither with ctrl+B. However, previewing with `ctrl+4` works for me.